# C Linked List Head Pointer is changing data value

Tags: c

I am writing a custom shell for class. I have the shell working but now I need to keep track of which commands are called by the user in a linked list, and then be able to print out these commands in a similar fashion to the `history()` command. The program seems to build the linked list fine however upon printing out with `history(list)` I begin to see errors.  After several commands are entered the command and string data values for the nodes begin to change. I have checked to make sure that the addresses the pointers are pointing to stay the same, but somehow the data values are being effected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Node{
  char* command;
  char* string;
  struct Node *next;
};

struct List{
  struct Node* front;
  struct Node* rear;
};


void shell_loop(void);
char *read_input(void);
char **split_input(char *input);

struct Node* createNode(char* command, char* string);
struct List* createList();
struct List* add_to_end(struct List *Q, char* command, char* string);
void history(struct List* Q);



const int TOKEN_BUFSIZE = 64;
const char* DELIMITER = " \t\r\n\a";
//#define EXIT_FAILURE


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    shell_loop();
}


void shell_loop(void)
{
char *input;
char **arguments;
char* command;
char* string;


struct List* list = createList();

   for(int i =0; i < 20; i++) 
   {

    printf("User> ");

    input = read_input();

    arguments = split_input(input);

    command = arguments[0];

    string = arguments[1];

    list = add_to_end(list, command, string);

    printf("\n");
    history(list); 
    printf("\n");

    free(input);
    free(arguments);
    }
}

char *read_input(void)
{
    char* input;
    size_t bufsize = 1000;
    getline(&input, &bufsize, stdin);

    return input;
}

char **split_input(char *input)
{
    int size_of_buffer = TOKEN_BUFSIZE, position = 0;
    char **tokens = malloc(size_of_buffer * sizeof(char*));
    char *token;

    if(!tokens)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "shell: allocation error\n");
        exit(1); // fix later
    }

    token = strtok(input, DELIMITER);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        tokens[position] = token;
        position ++;

    if(position >= size_of_buffer)
    {
        size_of_buffer += TOKEN_BUFSIZE;
        tokens = realloc(tokens, size_of_buffer * sizeof(char*));

        if(!tokens)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "shell: allocation error \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // fix later
        }
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
}

    tokens[position] = NULL;
    return tokens;
}


struct Node* createNode(char* c, char* s)
{
struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
temp->command = c;
temp->string = s;
temp->next = NULL;
return temp;
}

struct List* createList()
{
struct List* Q = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
Q->front = NULL;
Q->rear = NULL;
return Q;
}

struct List* add_to_end(struct List *Q, char* c, char* s)
{
   struct Node* temp = createNode(c, s);

   if(Q->front == NULL)
   {
    Q->front = temp;
    Q->rear = temp;
    temp = NULL;
    return Q;
    }

   Q->rear->next = temp;
   Q->rear = temp;
   temp = NULL;
   return Q;
}


void history(struct List* Q)
{
struct Node* current;
if (Q->front == NULL)
{
    printf("Command List is empty!\n");
    return;
}

current = Q->front;

while(current !=NULL)
{
    printf("Command: %s\nString: %s\n", current->command, current->string);
    current = current->next;
}

}
```

I have attached an output file of the history command to highlight how the first entered command eventually changes:

[image: output]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just shuffling pointer to stack data around, you need to copy the actual strings

```
 command = strdup(arguments[0]);

    string = strdup(arguments[1]);
```

Comment: This is just one problem, the other problem is addressed by Paul Ogilvie's answer.

Comment: This turned out to the main issue I was trying to solve, thanks for the help it works now!

Comment: note - when you free the nodes from your list you must free these two fields too otherwise you will leak. BTW, if on linux learn to use valgrind as a way of finding and tracking down leaks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `temp->string = strdup(s)` in `createNode(...)` instead of `temp->string = s`

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `getline` is wrong.

> If `*lineptr` is set to NULL and `*n` is set 0 before the call, then
>          getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
>          should be freed by the user program. ... Alternatively, before calling `getline()`, `*lineptr` can contain a
>          pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer `*n` bytes in size

Since `*n` is 1000 and `input` is uninitialized (points nowhere), `getline` assumes there is a buffer of 1000 chars available...which isn't.

Your call should be:

```
char *read_input(void)
{
    char* input= 0;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    getline(&input, &bufsize, stdin);

    return input;
}
```

See the comments and other solutions for the other problems of your program.

Comment: This is just one problem, the other problem is addressed by pm's answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, indeed, lots of problems.

Comment: Maybe there are even more problems, I didn't check in detail.

Comment: This was an error that I had not updated before copying over